# Am I doing this approximation correctly? (least squares method)

Tags: numerical-methods, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces, least-squares

Here is the problem. Find the function $f$ of the type $f(x) = a\cos x + b\sin x$ which best approximates the function $g$ in the points :
$$
\begin{array}{ c | c | c | c | c | c | c }
x & -3\frac{\pi}{4} & -\frac{\pi}{2} & -\frac{\pi}{4} & \frac{\pi}{4} & \frac{\pi}{2} & 3\frac{\pi}{4} \\
\hline
g(x) & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}
$$

using the least squares method. This is how I'm doing it. $g \in V$ - the linear space of all the functions defined in the given points and $f$ should be a function contained in the subspace $W$ of $V$ generated by $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. The norm of $V$ is $(s,t) = \sum_{i=1}^{6} s(x_i)t(x_i)$. So the conditions for $f$ should be $$(g - f, \cos) = 0 \text{ and } (g-f, \sin) = 0$$

From $(g-f, \cos) = 0$ I get $$\sum_{i = 1}^{6}(g(x_i)-a\cos x_i - b\sin x_i)\cos x_i = 0$$ from where substituting with the given data I conclude that $a = 0$. Similarly from $(g-f, \sin) = 0$ I get $b = \frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}$. So the answer has to be $$f(x) = \frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2} \sin x$$ Is this the correct answer and is there any method I can verify it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you plotted the two to see how they look?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: @martycohen Yeah but in this case it doesn't help much...

Comment: Looks like a square wave. Its Fourier transform is well known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g$ is clearly and odd function, and cosine is even and sine is odd, the coefficient of cosine will have to be $0$, and that's what you got.  And you can check by subsitution whether your two linear equations are satisfied by the answer you got.

Comment: You mean that if the function is odd then its approximation should be odd too?

Comment: @brick : You're approximating the function by a linear combination of functions in a specified set in which some of the members of the set are even functions and some are odd.  In those circumstances, the approximation should odd if the function you're approximating is odd.  If you had some functions that are neither even nor odd among those you're taking linear combinations of, then in some cases that is not true.